# After Upgrading to Visual Studio 16.8.5 Browser not Displaying Changes to Web Page

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I upgraded to VS 16.8.5 (16.8.4) and now, when I run my website in debug, changes I make to my web pages don't appear in the browser. For example...I have a .aspx page that is part of a website, I make a change, save, launch the page in my browser, but the change isn't there. I've tried:

- switching my debug browser between Chrome and Firefox
- rebuilding the page, website, and solution (all of which work fine)
- ctrl+F5

The only things that seem to work are closing/reopening the whole solution, or, stopping IIS express and rerunning the code but neither of these are workable solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why the VS upgrade would've caused this issue, but I think I found a solution:

Tools => Options => Projects & Solutions => Web Projects => check the box that says "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for websites and projects"

This appears to have solved the issue for me.